# Speculative Evolution Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have seen a few handfuls of subjects on Stack Exchange--Worldbuilding, Biology, Earth Science, Science Fiction & Fantasy and Astronomy.  In relation, my question is this--can we create a Speculative Biology/Evolution Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3):

You know that you can propose new sites on [area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), right? So if you want to have a new site, this is the place where you can really start it.

However, there have been some attempts at "what ifs" sites, which were so far all closed due to a too speculative nature. And [biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) already exists.

You'll need a concept to explain why biology.SE and worldbuilding.SE aren't sufficient. And to show that you will get good questions and answer. Not only too broad ones (like the other what-ifs).

Luckily you don't have to do all of it alone :) If you want to discuss it in more details, I'd suggest joining the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor).

Comment: Chat is too small.

Comment: Not chat to discuss the speculative biology, but chat to discuss how to start a new site

Comment: It's still Chat, which is still too small to post the really big scenarios.

Comment: This seems to be the current iteration of that proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102571/speculative-natural-science?referrer=Ia_ViotB3PAGdJ2mbrmycA2